# which is time consuming construct in following program?

Tags: c++, algorithm

while submitting a solution for practise problem 6(odd) i got TLE error
but while using using print and scanf in place cin and cout my sol was submitted successfully with 0.77s time..i want to know how can i make it more efficient
link to problem is [codechef problem 6](http://www.codechef.com/problems/DCE05/)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,N;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int l=0;l<n;l++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&N); 
        int i=0,x; 
        if(N<=0)
        continue; 
        for(;N>=(x=(2<<i));i++);
        printf("%d",x/2); 
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading this program is time consuming, given how it is formatted.  That said, the correct answer is:  run your code under a profiler and see which part of it is slow...

Comment: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html . It's pretty easy. Compile with compiler command line option `-pg`, `./run_my_code`, `gprof ./run_my_code > profile.txt`.

Comment: Which do you think are? What have you tried till now?

Comment: The problem page says that all submitted solutions are available. Have you checked the better solutions?

Comment: yes i did..and thats what made me more confuse..saw solution which is using same concept but with time 0 ,i want to know which one is more effificient using 2<<i or int o=2; while(condition)o=o*2;

Comment: You have created a program that meets the requirements. That's good, and you are done! As a professional programmer, this is what you do all the time - the program is good enough, so you go on and write your next program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is effectively greatest power of 2 <= n.

I used the following function from hackers delight to solve this:

```
unsigned int pow2 (unsigned int x){

        x = x | (x >> 1);
        x = x | (x >> 2);
        x = x | (x >> 4);
        x = x | (x >> 8);
        x = x | (x >> 16);

        return x - (x >> 1);
}
```

and got accepted in 0.75 sec.

I wonder what could be faster than this. I can see some submissions with `0`sec !!.

Comment: wow i tried one code submitted with 0 sec and it giving me TLE error now

Answer (score 1):

Well, you really have to find the largest power of two less than the given number.
So, you can try out the following.

```
scanf("%ld,&given_number);
dummy=1;
while(dummy < given_number) {
     dummy*=2;
}
printf("%ld",dummy/2);
```

Comment: i always though bitwise operation are always being more efficient

Comment: @user388338, most compilers will go to some effort to pick the fastest of bitshifting or multiplication for the target platform for inputs like this one, where one number is known ahead of time.

Comment: perhaps using `dummy < given_number/2` and removing the division in the output would also help -- it takes away one execution of the loop.

Comment: @sarnold: I really don't know how much it is going to impact the execution time of the program

Comment: @user388338: You know that, and so does the compiler writers. So obviously they transform `*=2` into `<< 1`, whenever that is better. We, as programmers, shouldn't bother with that kind of low level optimizations. Leave that to the computer!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the tester is including compile time too?

```
$ time gcc -std=c99 -o time time.c
real        0m0.082s
user        0m0.040s
sys 0m0.020s

$ time g++ -o time time.c++
real        0m0.210s
user        0m0.160s
sys 0m0.030s
```

For the C99 version I simply removed the C++-isms and used `#include <stdio.h>`, and the C version compiles in less than half the time of the C++ version.

On my relatively bonkers machine (Core i7), runtimes of both takes around 1.7 seconds when output is to the terminal, and 0.05 seconds when output is to a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline unsigned int floorpow2(unsigned int x)
{
    for( unsigned int y; (y = x & (x-1)); )
        x = y;

    return x;
}
```